# Discord.js support channel

Tags: discord.js

I want to create an if variable which checks if a user joins a certain channel, if they do then I'll keep doing my program.

What I have tried so far is different things like:

```js
client.on('channel', async channel => {
    if (channel.member.join(channel => channel.id === `672920107457970177`)) {
        working.send("did it work??")
    }
})
```

But I am pretty sure that my whole script is wrong; I only started using discord.js a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Client's `voiceStateUpdate` event. It will return 2 GuildMember values. The old one and the updated one.

```
Client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!oldMember.voiceChannel && newMember.voiceChannel) {
        console.log("oldMember channel doesn't exist. newMember channel exist. User joined a voice channel.")
    } else if (!newMember.voiceChannel) {
        console.log("newMember voice channel doesn't exist. User left a voice channel.")
    }
})
```

You need to do these checks because `voiceStatusUpdate` is fired whenever the voice status updates (e.g. defean, mute, channel move etc.)

To check if the user joined a certain channel, just check the ID:

```
Client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!oldMember.voiceChannel && newMember.voiceChannel && newMember.voiceChannelID == "CHANNEL ID") {
        console.log(`User joined ${newMember.voiceChannel.name}!`)
    }
})
```